# Geolocation distance

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm creating a nike + run style app.

Example: The user presses play and the application starts to count the distance it has traveled and speed.

But searching for geolocation and ionic, I visualized a problem: if the user close the application the geolocation stops working. I also noticed that there is a way to always make it active, but I have doubts if Apple would accept it.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Background Geolocation plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation/

Comment: I had searched for this same plugin, but I noticed this issue that when I close the application the background stops.

Is this the expected behavior? Maybe it is anyway

Comment: I haven't tried It recently but wouldn't be the first time a Cordova plugin went buggy. There's a logging function for debugging. Maybe see if any errors are caught there.